# Woocommerce Local Pickup Plus - modify to force all items to be picked up

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am working with the Local Pickup Plus plugin for woocommerce and it is almost everything that I need, except for the fact that the customer has to manually select every product in the cart as either shipping or local pickup.

I was wondering if there was an easy way to force the customer to have all items shipped or all items picked up

Comment: You could put buttons on the cart page that said "ship all items" or "pick up all items"

Comment: Could I modify the way the plugin works so that by clicking on pickup selects pickup for all cart items?

Comment: Interesting, I have exactly the same issue, its not very robust

Comment: @timboon yes, definitely.

Comment: @JacobRaccuia do you have any documentation to help me do that? not really sure where to start

Comment: @timboon nope :) Sounds like you could do it with javascript though and just emulate the action of selecting one at a time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this by writing my own function to only do what I was specifically looking for. This function adds the option to select from a drop down which store to pickup from and then updates the shipping accordingly.

```
    /**
 * Add store location select dropdown in checkout page
 **/
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_store_pickup_field');

function custom_store_pickup_field( $fields ) {

      $fields['billing']['store_pickup'] = array(
        'type'     => 'select',
        'options'  => array(
        'option_0'=> 'Please Select a Delivery Option',
        'option_1' => 'Delivery',
        'option_2' => 'Gym1',
        'option_3' => 'Gym2'
        ),
     'label'     => __('Delivery or Store Pickup', 'woocommerce'),
    'required'  => true,
    'class'     => array('store-pickup form-row-wide'),
    'id'        => 'store_pickup_val',
    'clear'     => true
     );


     return $fields;
}

//* Process the checkout
 add_action('woocommerce_checkout_process', 'wps_select_checkout_field_process');
 function wps_select_checkout_field_process() {
    global $woocommerce;
    // Check if set, if its not set add an error.
    if ($_POST['store_pickup'] == "option_0")
     wc_add_notice( '<strong>Please select a day part under Delivery options</strong>', 'error' );
 }


add_action( 'woocommerce_after_checkout_form', 'gym_opening_hours', 6);

function gym_opening_hours() {

  ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery('#store_pickup_val').change(function(){

            jQuery('body').trigger('update_checkout');


            jQuery( ".gym-collection" ).remove(); 

            if (this.value == 'option_1') {
                jQuery('#shipping_method_0_flat_rate1').prop('checked', true);
            }

            if (this.value == 'option_2') {
                 jQuery( "<p>Order can be collected between 4pm - 7pm on Tuesdays</p>" ).addClass("gym-collection").insertAfter( "#store_pickup_val" );
                 jQuery('#shipping_method_0_local_pickup3').prop('checked', true);  
            } 
                if (this.value == 'option_3') {
                 jQuery( "<p>Order can be collected between 4pm - 7pm on Tuesdays</p>" ).addClass("gym-collection").insertAfter( "#store_pickup_val" );
                 jQuery('#shipping_method_0_local_pickup3').prop('checked', true);          
            } 
            else {

            }

        });
    </script>
    <?php

}


# add this in your plugin file and that's it, the calculate_shipping method of your shipping plugin class will be called again
function action_woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review($array, $int)
{
    WC()->cart->calculate_shipping();
    return;
}
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review', 'action_woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review', 10, 2);
?>

 <?php
```